# NetBeans + GitHub = git-receive-pack not permitted

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Estou utilizado o git para fazer o controle de um projeto da faculdade, estamos utilizando o netbeans+eclipse e um amigo que participa do projeto me enviou o link do git, fiz o clone do projeto, porem não consigo fazer fazer o push no netbeans. é exibida a mensagem de erro git-receive-pack not permitted

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se o seu usuário esta adicionado como colaborador nas configurações do repositório no GitHub.

Peça para o dono do repositório acessar as configurações e na segunda opção, "Collaborators" ele poderá incluir seu usuário do git ou email.

Abraço.